# How to exit a program minimized to tray just with keybooard

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

I know I can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd> to get the task manager to exit a program.  But is there a another way?

I can press <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and go to tray, but what after?

Comment: Alt + Tab to it and hit Alt + F4?

Answer (score 2):

There are some answers mentioned you can choose the tray icon and exit it, but if you want to close some program with one single shortcut combination, here is the solution:

1. You type `taskkill /f /im "theProcessNameGoesHere.exe"` in notepad, replace `theProcessNameGoesHere.exe` in your actual program name, save it in `kill_program.bat`, create a shortcut of the saved batch file.
2. Right click the the shortcut properties, in the Shortcut column, press the key that you perfer to close the program
   [image]

Comment: This will work, but there definitely is another way without creating a workaround. So I can't vote up your answer because you say there isn't. Won't vote it down either, because the OP may prefer this option to using a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @LPChip Yup, I misread this question, I thought he was looking for a keyboard shortcut,(one step to close it), will revise the answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Most programs that are in the system tray, have an EXIT right in the context menu.

So what you want to do is the following:

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to make the focus on the system tray area.

Use the arrow keys to select the application that you want to close. Now hit <kbd>space</kbd> left mouse button action or <kbd>menu</kbd> (alternative <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>) right mouse button action or <kbd>enter</kbd> default action to open its menu and use the arrow keys to close the program or open it so you can close it from within the program itself.

I'm aware that not every keyboard has the menu button, so the alternative would be shift-f10.

[image]
Figure 1: Showing the menu key.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what i am look for.
In fact I know win + b, and shift + F10, but it didn't work yes today and I thought may the location of cursor might be the reason.
But when I try like you said, it works. When win and b are pressed, the logical cursor does go to system tray area, and then shift + F10 will work.
So thank you very much, problem solved.And Credit goes to you.
Thank other ones too.

Comment: Glad I could help Jiro. Can you mark the answer as solved so everyone can see you no longer need help?

Answer (score 0):

A more generic way to do what @Bilo suggests is to use the Run command (`Win`+`R`), or just the Windows Start search/Cortana, followed by typing `taskkill /f /im *processname.exe*` and hitting `Enter`.

If you don't know the program name and want to use the systray and keyboard directly, it's a little trickier but usually possible. After hitting `Win`+`B`, you'll have the try selected. You can expand it, if needed, by hitting `Space`. When it's expanded, you can highlight items in it using the arrow keys. Highlight the one you want, then press `Enter` if you want to do the same thing as left-clicking it. If you want to do the same thing as right-clicking (which is the most likely way to get a menu with a "Quit" option), use the `Menu` key. Not all keyboards have this, but if they do it's usually near the right `Ctrl` key, under the right `Shift` key. Hitting that will open the right-click menu for the highlighted item. You can then use arrow keys to select the `Quit` option, and hit `Enter`.

Comment: -1 from me because you basically state what already was given in 2 other answers and the small addition yours have should've been worked out better.

Comment: @LPChip: I wrote my answer before yours was posted. If you really want to throw -1s over it (even though I did, also, add content; not everybody knows you can launch Run from Win+R, sadly, or run commands from Start search) that seems rather petty but hey, it's the Internet. You could have done something useful like suggest an edit if you thought my addition needed work, though.

Comment: I'm very sure my answer was on before yours. Maybe you started to write yours before mine appeared, I can't check that, but when I submitted my answer yours wasn't there yet, and I edited a few times before yours popped up.